# Ball bouncing issue

Tags: javascript

"I have tried to use some of the basic motion equation : v^2 = u^2 + 2as, and multiplied it with a variable : bouncing_factor. This gave me a very good animation, but I want the ball to gradually slow down & then stop. If bouncing_factor is 0 then the ball does a weird movement. Please fox these two issues.  "

```js
{  var c = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        var width = 600;
        var height = 600;

  var x = width / 2;
  var y = 100;
  var r = 50;
  var mass = 1;

  var vY = 0;
  var a = 0.2;

  var ground = height - r;
  var bouncing_factor = 1; // keep this <1 & >0

  function draw() {
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

   if (y < ground) {
    // gives acceleration
    vY += a;
    y += vY; 
   } else {
    vY = -Math.sqrt (vY * vY + 2 * a * 500) * bouncing_factor;
     y = (ground - 1);
    }

   // ball
   ctx.fillStyle = "red";
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
   ctx.fill(); 

   requestAnimationFrame(draw); // loops this function
  }
  draw();}
```

```html
<canvas id='gameCanvas'></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment the ball will hit ground, it will just **reverse** its motion and gets **damped** by some factor.

`vY = -vY * bouncing_factor;`

If after a lot of damping, the ball is **no more able to bounce** above the ground, then you can cancel the animation frame request by using [`cancelAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame)

```
if(y > ground && Math.abs(vY) < a+1) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(request);
}
```

You can see the logic [working here](https://jsfiddle.net/r_v_7/ne0hafc5/1/)

Answer (score 2):

I think  the equation is not right for reflecting a bouncing ball effect.
Please use this equation

[image]

h- the height from which the ball is dropped
g- gravity (you can change this according to your need)
t- time